# Why is resources in the routes.rb file not creating ALL of the routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, crud, rails-routing, activeresource

I am making a rails application.  After a user has registered (I have
already created user registration with devise), they can fill out this
form that will contain their profile information.  The form should
submit a post request to the create action in the informations controller, but for some reason I can't configure the routes properly.  When i run rake routes, for informations#create, which is what the form should be going to, it has a blank path. There is also informations#index, which is what I guess its going to now. How do I get the form to go to informations#create if the path is blank?  I have done this several times, and i can't find what is wrong.  Here is the model:

```
class Information < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is the controller:

```
class InformationsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @information = Information.new
    end
    def create
        @information = Information.create(params[:information])
        redirect_to student_path
    end
    def index
    end
end
```

And here is the view for the new action.

```
<div class="span6 offset3 text-center">
<h1>Edit your information</h1>

    <%= simple_form_for @information do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :skills %>


        <%= f.input :looking_for, :label => 'What help do you need?' %>
        <%= f.input :my_idea %>
        <%= submit_tag "Save", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is the line in the routes file:

```
resources :informations
```

I get the following error:

undefined method `information_index_path' for #<#:0x007f9c00c7b3e0>

Here is rake routes for the files

```
 informations GET    /informations(.:format)          informations#index
             POST   /informations(.:format)          informations#create
```

Here is my full stacktrace when trying to load the page that shows the form:

```
Started GET "/informations/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-21 17:25:09 -0400
Processing by InformationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered informations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (64.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 70ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `information_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff03e8b34a0>:0x007ff03e8b23e8>):
    2:  <div class="span6 offset3 text-center">
    3:  <h1>Edit your information</h1>
    4: 
    5:      <% simple_form_for @information do |f| %>
    6:          <%= f.input :skills %>
    7:          
    8:          
  app/views/informations/new.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_informations_new_html_erb__3172218935119285240_70334909089600'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@firehose/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@firehose/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@firehose/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (9.1ms)


Started GET "/informations/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-21 17:25:09 -0400
Processing by InformationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered informations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `information_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff03e8b34a0>:0x007ff03e8708a8>):
    2:  <div class="span6 offset3 text-center">
    3:  <h1>Edit your information</h1>
    4: 
    5:      <% simple_form_for @information do |f| %>
    6:          <%= f.input :skills %>
    7:          
    8:          
  app/views/informations/new.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_informations_new_html_erb__3172218935119285240_70334908978600'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@firehose/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@firehose/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@firehose/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (14.0ms)
```

Comment: which line is the error from?

Comment: Please post your full stacktrace

Comment: I am not sure what a stacktrace is.  Do you mean what it says in the terminal when i access the page?

Comment: yeah, the whole exception

Comment: OK.  I made an edit and added the stacktrace.

Comment: First of all, the path to your `#create` action is NOT blank. The blank space that you see only means it uses the same path as the entry above it, but with a different HTTP action (POST instead of GET).

Comment: oh ok.  so how do i get it to go to post?  I added the rake resources output to the question.  With @information, it does get which takes it to informations#index.  I need it to do post and go to informations#create .

Comment: Normally you shouldn't have to do anything. Rails should make the form do a POST by itself, just by internally doing a `@information.new_record?`. You're doing two things out of the ordinary, but I'm not sure they're related to your problem. One, you should use the rendering ERB tag with `simple_form_for` -- the one with the equal sign. Two, you should use `f.button :submit` instead of `submit_tag`.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed those in my code.  Unfortunately, it does not fix the issue

Comment: Your problem may be related to the fact that the word *information* is both the plural and the singular form. Just like *water*, or *paper*, or *evidence*. That may throw off Rails. You might wanna try naming your model something else to see what happens.

Comment: Depa, I think your comment worked!  If you officially andswer the question, I'll mark it correct.  Unless there's a way to mark your comment correct.

Comment: Nice, let me post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to the fact that the word *information* is both the plural and the singular form. Just like *water*, or *paper*, or *evidence*. Rails considers those words `uncountable`.

There are two things you can do: either name your model something else or edit the file `config/initializers/inflections.rb` like so:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w( information )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form should be for one single information object. Not for a collection of information objects. Note that i have changed `simple_form_for @informations` to `simple_form_for @information`

```
<div class="span6 offset3 text-center">
<h1>Edit your information</h1>

    <% simple_form_for @information do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :skills %>


        <%= f.input :looking_for, :label => 'What help do you need?' %>
        <%= f.input :my_idea %>
        <%= submit_tag "Save", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Also your failure is not because rails didn't generate information_index_path. Its because the named route for information#index is `informations_path`. the path is generated wrongly because you are using collection of objects.

Comment: No, I mistyped it into stack overflow.  In the document i have @information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but try adding a = in front of simple_form_for. so that it will have a <%= instead of <%